# atualização do perfil de usuário / Angular-Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.authService.usuario$.subscribe( user => {
      this.initValuesForm(user);
      console.log('user', user)
    })
  }
    
  private initValuesForm(user: Usuario): void{
      this.profileForm.patchValue({
        displayName: user.displayName,
        empresa: user.empresa,
        email: user.email,
        phone: user.phone,
      })
     
  }


  onSubmit(usuario: Usuario):void{
    this.authService.saveUserProfile(usuario)
}
```

Esse é o código do meu perfil.component.ts
Quando eu faço o click no botão, o click realmente funciona mas os dados não são armazenados/atualizados no firebase

Comment: Tu poderias dar mais detalhes? Há algum erro? Poderias fornecer um exemplo mínimo verificável, para que a comunidade possa executar localmente e reproduzir o problema, para te ajudar na correção?

Comment: Acabei não colocando todas as partes do código, mas quando faço o submit das forms do HTML, ele atribui as forms ao submit mas não joga no firebase

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: No document to update: projects/beerserv-inv/databases/(default)/documents/usuarios/undefined
FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/beerserv-inv/databases/(default)/documents/usuarios/undefined`

Não há retorno do UID, quando faço o update consta que não há referencia no BD